# ASP.NET MVC: как запретить доступ к изображению по ссылке в атрибуте src?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Существует ли официальный и отработанный способ запрета доступа к изображению по ссылке в img src="..."? Все что удалось найти в поисковиках - либо реализовано через задний проход, либо не работает. А то получается, что не спрячешь никак приватные фотки... А надо...

Comment: Да. Этот способ называется "авторизация пользователя".

Comment: Любой авторизованный и не авторизованный пользователь через прямую ссылку к файлу изображения может смотреть фотку другого авторизованного пользователя.

Comment: Вы можете это запретить

Comment: фотку очевидно контроллер должен выдавать, после проверки всех прав. не ссылку на нее, а именно сам контент. то есть у вас должен быть а-ля `<img src="ImgController/showImage">`

Comment: Да, спасибо всем, получилось. Запретил доступ к файлам с помощью RegisterRoutes, а картинки получаю в виде массива байтов из контроллера